Protocol 'Identifiable' requires 'id' to be available in iOS 16.0 and newer
Creating Tipkit but this error is appearing, complete beginner any help would be much appreciated Xcode Image Please Give Code solution
import Foundation
import TipKit

struct Example: Tip {  // Protocol 'Identifiable' requires 'id' to be available in iOS 16.0 and newer  
    var title: Text {
        Text("Example Tip")
    }
    var message: Text? {
        Text("Example Tip Subtitle")
    }
    var image: Image? {
        Image(systemName: "globe")
    }
}

Tipkit Requires iOS 17.0 or newer, but deployment target or project is 16.0 or to fix?

I can’t reproduce, what is the target os for your project?

Tip is only available for iOS 17+ you have to limit tips to that version https://developer.apple.com/documentation/tipkit/tip the answer isn’t going to change the more you ask the same question. You can use “available” to limit tips for 17 there is no way to use them in 16

As stated in the comments, you have to make your tips iOS 17 only:
import TipKit

@available(iOS 17.0, *) // <<< The important part
struct Example: Tip {  
    var title: Text { Text("Example Tip") }
    ...
}

